# how write rewrite rule by using .htaccess in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

This is an example of how I want the URL to be rewritten:

Visible url is `localhost/foldername/task/task_title/task_id`
Back End Url is `localhost/foldername/task.php?task_id=1213`

I wrote this line in my .htaccess file:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule /task/[a-zA-z0-9]+/([0-9]+) /task.php?task_id=$3 

 #front url: task/task title/taskid#
 #back_end url: task.php?task_id=1233
```

This does not work and shows errors "Internal Server Error" and "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.".

How do I have to fix my rewrite rule for these type of urls?

Answer (score 0):

The rules would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(foldername/task)/[a-z0-9]+/(\d+)/?$ /$1.php?task_id=$2 [NC,L]
```